# CloudKit perform

Tags: ios, cloudkit

i have an issue with CloudKit in my App. The Data loads perfectly when the view is loaded initially. But when I "Pull to Refresh" I get a "fatal error: Index out of range". Strange thing is that there is no difference in Code (at least for me).
When I pull to refresh, it does not even run "perform" ("B" does not get printed).
Debugger does not show any error.

Do you have a clue?

Thanks in advance!

Nico

**viewDidLoad**:

```
loadCloudData()
```

**handlePullToRefresh**:

```
func handlePullToRefresh() {
    loadCloudData()
}
```

**loadCloudData**:

```
func loadCloudData() {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.showMessage(titleText: NSLocalizedString("Loading ...", comment: "SwiftMessage Loading Title"), text: NSLocalizedString("Loading PixelCodes from Cloud", comment: "SwiftMessage Loading Title"), backgroundColor: UIColor.tileYellow(), textColor: UIColor.darkGray, image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "cloud"))
        }

        dataCloud = [CKRecord]()
        let query = CKQuery(recordType: PixelCodeType.recordType, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "TRUEPREDICATE", argumentArray: nil))
        query.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "title", ascending: true)]

        print("A")

        databasePublic.perform(query, inZoneWith: nil) { (results:[CKRecord]?, error:Error?) in
            print("B")
            if error != nil {
                print("PixelCode from Cloud not Loaded!\n\(error!.localizedDescription)")
                self.couldLoadCloadData = false
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    SwiftMessages.hideAll()

                    if self.refreshControl != nil {
                        if self.refreshControl!.isRefreshing {
                            self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
                        }
                    }

                    //"Cloud" active
                    self.segmentedControl.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1)
                }
                self.handleError(title: NSLocalizedString("Error!", comment: "SwiftMessage error title"), text: error!.localizedDescription, errorTitle: "Cloud Loading Error:loadCloudData()", error: error)
            } else {
                if let data = results {
                    print("pixelCodes updated")
                    self.dataCloud = data

                    if results!.isEmpty {
                        self.couldLoadCloadData = true
                        self.isCloudDataLoaded = false
                    } else {
                        self.couldLoadCloadData = true
                        self.isCloudDataLoaded = true
                    }

                    self.uploadTimes()

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        if self.refreshControl != nil {
                            if self.refreshControl!.isRefreshing {
                                self.refreshControl!.endRefreshing()
                            }
                        }
                        SwiftMessages.hideAll()

                        //"Cloud" active
                        self.segmentedControl.setEnabled(true, forSegmentAt: 1)

                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing that your `loadCloudData` function does is set the `dataCloud` array to an empty array, but you don't call `reloadData` on the tableview so the number of items in the array and the number of items that the tableview *thinks* is in the array is different.

You should either call `reloadData` after you clear the array or not clear the array.

Comment: I removed "dataCloud = [CKRecord]()" and everything works fine! I don't know why I did not think about removing it. Thanks a lot!!!